# BigQuery returns null for REGEXP_MATCH or _EXTRACT

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the following the following query to return a subset of a string in a column:

```
    SELECT
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(content, r'/\ :dependencies\ \[(.*?)\]]\ /g') AS deps
    FROM x[my-test-162023:lab.clj_files_results_030904]
```

but returns the following:

```
Row deps     
1   null     
2   null     
3   null     
4   null     
5   null     
6   null
```

I've tested the regex pattern on http://www.regexpal.com/ and https://regex101.com/r/Gjre2i/2 and it seems to be working.

Any help/hints are appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
The table I'm trying to query is looks like the following:

```
Row content  
1   (defproject spaghetti "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" :description "FIXME: write description" :url "http://example.com/FIXME" :license {:name "Eclipse Public License" :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"} :source-paths ["src/clj" "src/cljs"] :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"] [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2371" :scope "provided"] [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"] [ring "1.3.1"] [compojure "1.2.0"] [enlive "1.1.5"] [om "0.7.3"] [figwheel "0.1.4-SNAPSHOT"] [environ "1.0.0"] [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.1.3"] [weasel "0.4.3-SNAPSHOT"] [leiningen "2.5.0"] [http-kit "2.1.19"] [com.cognitect/transit-cljs "0.8.188"] ; [devcards "0.1.2-SNAPSHOT"] [sablono "0.2.22"] [prismatic/om-tools "0.3.3"]] :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.3"] [lein-environ "1.0.0"]] :min-lein-version "2.5.0" :uberjar-name "spaghetti.jar" :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["src/cljs/spaghetti"] :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/app.js" :output-dir "resources/public/js/out" :source-map "resources/public/js/out.js.map" :optimizations :none :preamble ["react/react.min.js" "public/js/adsr/index.js" "public/js/WebMIDIAPIWrapper/js/WebMIDIAPIWrapper.js" "public/js/hammerjs/hammer.min.js" "public/js/wavy-jones/wavy-jones.js"] :externs ["react/externs/react.js" "public/js/adsr/adsr.externs.js" "public/js/WebMIDIAPIWrapper/WebMIDIAPIWrapper.externs.js" "public/js/hammerjs/hammerjs.externs.js" "public/js/wavy-jonewavy-jones.externs.js"] :pretty-print true}}}} :profiles {:dev {:repl-options {:init-ns spaghetti.server :timeout 120000 :nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]} :plugins [[lein-figwheel "0.1.4-SNAPSHOT"]] :figwheel {:http-server-root "public" :port 3449 :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]} :env {:is-dev true} :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["env/dev/cljs"]}}}} :uberjar {:hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild] :env {:production true} :omit-source true :aot :all :cljsbuild {:builds {:app {:source-paths ["env/prod/cljs"] :compiler {:optimizations :advanced :pretty-print false }}}}}})     
2   (defproject pomodoro "0.0.4" :license {:name "MIT" :url "http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT" :distribution :repo} :description "A simple pomodoro timer" :url "https://github.com/landau/cljs-pomodoro" :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"] [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2322"] [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.338.0-5c5012-alpha"] [com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time "0.1.6"] [reagent "0.4.2"]] :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.11"] [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.3"] [lein-environ "0.5.0"]] :ring {:handler server.core/app} :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all} :dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"] [ring/ring-devel "1.3.0"] [compojure "1.1.9"]] :env {:dev true}} :release {:ring {:open-browser? false :stacktraces? false :auto-reload? false}}} :source-paths ["src"] :main server.core :cljsbuild { :builds [{:id "dev" :source-paths ["src-cljs"] :compiler {:output-to "public/js/pomodoro.js" :output-dir "public/js/dev" :optimizations :none :pretty-print tru :source-map true}} {:id "prod" :source-paths ["src-cljs"] :compiler {:output-to "public/js/main.js" :optimizations :advanced :pretty-print false :externs ["public/js/react-min-0.11.2.js"] }}]})    
3   (defproject datascript-mori "0.15.2" :description "Wrapper for datascript interplay mori" :url "https://github.com/typeetfunc/datascript-mori" :license {:name "Eclipse Public License" :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"} :min-lein-version "2.5.3" :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"] [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.170"] [datascript "0.15.0"]] :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.2" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]] [lein-git-deps "0.0.2-SNAPSHOT"]] :git-dependencies [["https://github.com/swannodette/mori.git"]] :source-paths ["src" ".lein-git-deps/mori/src"] :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["target"] :cljsbuild {:builds [{:id "min" :source-paths ["src" ".lein-git-deps/mori/src"] :compiler { :output-to "release-js/datascript-mori.bare.js" :main datascript-mori.core :optimizations :advanced :pretty-print false } :notify-command ["release-js/wrap_bare.sh"]}]} )    
4   (defproject pandect "0.6.1-SNAPSHOT" :description "Message Digest and Checksum Library for Clojure" :url "https://github.com/xsc/pandect" :license {:name "MIT License" :url "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT" :year 2014 :key "mit"} :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0" :scope "provided"] [org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on "1.54" :scope "provided"]] :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure] :source-paths ["src/clojure" "target/generated"] :java-source-paths ["src/java"] :profiles {:dev {:plugins [[lein-codox "0.9.4"]] :codox {:project {:name "pandect"} :metadata {:doc/format :markdown} :output-path "doc" :namespaces [pandect.core pandect.buffer #"^pandect\.algo\.[a-z\-]+"]}} :benchmark {:dependencies [[criterium "0.4.3"] [clj-message-digest "1.0.0"] [digest "1.4.4"]] :source-paths ["shootout"] :jvm-opts ^:replace ["-Xmx1g" "-server"]} :1.5 {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]]} :1.6 {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]]} :1.7 {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]]}} :prep-tasks ["codegen"] :aliases {"benchmark" ["with-profile" "dev,benchmark" "run" "-m"] "codegen" ["run" "-m" "pandect.codegen"] "all" ["with-profile" "+dev:+1.5:+1.6:+1.7"]} :pedantic? :abort)  
5   (defproject stch-library/sql "0.1.1" :description "A DSL in Clojure for SQL query, DML, and DDL." :url "https://github.com/stch-library/sql" :license {:name "Eclipse Public License" :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"} :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"] [stch-library/schema "0.3.3"]] :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[speclj "3.0.2"]]}} :plugins [[speclj "3.0.2"] [codox "0.6.7"]] :codox {:src-dir-uri "https://github.com/stch-library/sql/blob/master/" :src-linenum-anchor-prefix "L"} :test-paths ["spec"])    
6   (defproject laboratory "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT" :description "do science in production" :url "https://github.com/yeller/laboratory" :license {:name "Eclipse Public License" :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"} :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]] :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.4"]]} :benches {:dependencies [[criterium "0.4.1"]] :source-paths ["src" "benches"]}} :global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* true *unchecked-math* :warn-on-boxed ;*compiler-options* {:disable-locals-clearing true} *assert* true})
```

Comment: The regex here does not need delimiters. `r' :dependencies \[(.*?)\]] '` should work.

Comment: I've just tried that @WiktorStribiżew but with no success..

Comment: Try `r' :dependencies \[((?:\[[^\][]*(?:\[[^\][]*][^\][]*)*]|[^\][])*)] '` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/s9GSVp/1))

Comment: I've tried the following @WiktorStribiżew - ```SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(content,
    r' :dependencies \[((?:\[[^\][]*(?:\[[^\][]*][^\][]*)*]|[^\][])*)] ')
FROM
  [my-test-23:lab.clj_project_files]``` but with no luck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/g` means that you want to extract all matches, not just one which is what [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) does.
You should use [`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract_all) instead, along with [`UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest)

So try below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT deps
FROM `my-test-23.lab.clj_project_files`, 
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(content, r' :dependencies \[(.*?)\]] ')) AS deps
```

> got "Query returned zero records" ....

Try below with dummy data based on your example (just stripped first two rows)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '(defproject :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"] [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2371" :scope "provided"] [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"] [ring "1.3.1"] [compojure "1.2.0"] [enlive "1.1.5"] [om "0.7.3"] [figwheel "0.1.4-SNAPSHOT"] [environ "1.0.0"] [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.1.3"] [weasel "0.4.3-SNAPSHOT"] [leiningen "2.5.0"] [http-kit "2.1.19"] [com.cognitect/transit-cljs "0.8.188"] ; [devcards "0.1.2-SNAPSHOT"] [sablono "0.2.22"] [prismatic/om-tools "0.3.3"]] :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.3"] [lein-environ "1.0.0"]]  '  AS content UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '(defproject :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"] [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2322"] [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.338.0-5c5012-alpha"] [com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time "0.1.6"] [reagent "0.4.2"]] :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.11"] [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.3"] [lein-environ "0.5.0"]] :ring {:handler server.core/app} :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all} :dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"] [ring/ring-devel "1.3.0"] [compojure "1.1.9"]] :env {:dev true}}  ' 
)
SELECT id, deps
FROM yourTable, UNNEST(SPLIT(REPLACE(
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(content, r' :dependencies \[(\[.*?])*] ') 
  ,'] [', '],['))) AS deps
ORDER BY id
```

Result is as below

```sql
Row id  deps     
1   1   [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2371" :scope "provided"]     
2   1   [prismatic/om-tools "0.3.3"]     
3   1   [sablono "0.2.22"]   
4   1   [com.cognitect/transit-cljs "0.8.188"] ; [devcards "0.1.2-SNAPSHOT"]     
5   1   [http-kit "2.1.19"]  
6   1   [leiningen "2.5.0"]  
7   1   [weasel "0.4.3-SNAPSHOT"]    
8   1   [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.1.3"]    
9   1   [environ "1.0.0"]    
10  1   [figwheel "0.1.4-SNAPSHOT"]  
11  1   [om "0.7.3"]     
12  1   [enlive "1.1.5"]     
13  1   [compojure "1.2.0"]  
14  1   [ring "1.3.1"]   
15  1   [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]    
16  1   [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]    
17  2   [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]    
18  2   [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2322"]   
19  2   [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.338.0-5c5012-alpha"]    
20  2   [com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time "0.1.6"]    
21  2   [reagent "0.4.2"]
```

> ... but if I remove that and run it on my own dataset/table I don't get any results ...

Looks like your real data is "slightly" different from how it shown in your question

Try below - it should work now :o)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id, deps
FROM `my-test-23.lab.clj_project_files`, 
  UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(content, r'(?s) :dependencies \[(\[.*?])]') 
  , r']\n *\[', '],['))) AS deps
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: For some reason I get "Error: Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing."

Comment: @user228137 - in place of `yourTable` you need to put real full qualified table name like `project.dataset.table` surrounded with backticks - see updated answer

Comment: That's exactly what I did: ```SELECT
  deps
FROM
  [my-test-23.lab.clj_project_files],
  UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(content,
      r' :dependencies \[(.*?)\]] ')) AS deps``` but still get the above mentioned error..

Comment: you shouldn't use [ and ] here - rather backticks as in answer - because it is Standard SQL. Please try again and let us know

Comment: yes. I removed the square brackets. but got "Query returned zero records" with your regex pattern and 1 row with Wiktor's pattern: ```' :dependencies \[((?:\[[^\][]*(?:\[[^\][]*][^\][]*)*]|[^\][])*)] '```

Comment: so just change/fix pattern :o)  - i didn't have chance to follow this post closely :o) - if you still have a problem you should provide example of your actual data otherwise there is no way to help you more than already did

Comment: I've added an example. Let me know if you have any additional suggestions :)

Comment: @user228137 - i run query in my answer against sample data you provided and it works for me. are you saying that you still getting NO output at all or you have output but it is not what you expected  - please clarify!?

Comment: @user228137 - please check my update in answer. i had to tweak it a little to get it work the way I would expect it to be. Can you please try it and tell  me what you need to be different - so we will be able to get to final version. as I said I did a little tweak with replace and split but in reality it should be just better regex. but at the same time replace and split looks like do their job :o)

Comment: I get your results if I run the query using the WITH clause... but if I remove that and run it on my own dataset/table I don't get any results. For better understanding what the data I'm querying looks like see this exported CSV: https://storage.googleapis.com/to-share/test/test.csv

Comment: @user228137 - ok. i got it  - will check your data

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works now. I guess I should post real sample data in my questions instead of truncated/abstracted :)

Comment: @user228137 - in case like this one  - having real data to begin with -
 would help a lot and speed up the answer. but not in all cases you want to share real data :o)  btw - if not yet - please also consider vote up my answer :o) this is important on SO